# I am not able to hide the "Split pane bar" in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

This thing never exited before. All of a sudden it started showing up and I hate it. Can some one help me remove this please. I am running 10.11.5 OS X

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under the "View" menu select "Close Split Pane" or type <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

You probably typed <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> by accident.

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the icon in the scrollbar?!

Comment: this doesn't remove icon in the scrollbar :(